# Setting XML namespaces with the System.Xml.Linq API

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xnamespace

I'm having trouble generating XML along the lines of this:

```
<Root xmlns:brk="http://somewhere">
<child1>
    <brk:node1>123456</brk:node1>
    <brk:node2>500000000</brk:node2>
</child1>
</Root>
```

This code get me most of the way, but I can't get the 'brk' namespace in front of the nodes;

```
 var rootNode = new XElement("Root");
 rootNode.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "brk", "http://somewhere"));

 var childNode = new XElement("child1");
 childNode.Add(new XElement("node1",123456));
 rootNode.Add(childNode);
```

I've tried this:

```
XNamespace brk = "http://somewhere";
childNode.Add(new XElement(brk+"node1",123456));
```

and this

```
XNamespace brk = "http://somewhere";
childNode.Add(new XElement("brk:node1",123456));
```

but both cause exceptions.

Comment: What exception do you get? I get no exception and correct results when using childNode.Add(new XElement(brk+"node1",123456));

Comment: System.Xml.XmlException: The prefix '' cannot be redefined from '' to 'http://somewhere' within the same start element tag.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there, but you made one simple error in your first code example. I believe this is what you require:

```
XNamespace brk = "http://somewhere.com";
XElement root = new XElement("Root",
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "brk", "http://somewhere.com"));

XElement childNode = new XElement("child1");
childNode.Add(new XElement(brk + "node1",123456));
root.Add(childNode);
```

The main difference here is where I add `node1` to `childNode` as follows:

```
childNode.Add(new XElement(brk + "node1",123456));
```

This code, given an `XmlWriter` and `XDocument` gives me the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns:brk="http://somewhere.com">
  <child1>
    <brk:node1>123456</brk:node1>
  </child1>
</Root>
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.aspx) for details of using [`XNamespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.aspx).

Comment: Ok Yates, lets have a man hug, your just on the back foot because your envious of my var usage. I cant see why yours should work and not mine? can you tell me?

Comment: I'm down with the hug, but we'll have to keep that dirty var usage out of it - I don't want to catch anything.

I think that this is working because in your first code example, you don't do the 'brk + "node1"', you just do "node1".

Comment: Interestingly, I tried your second code example where you include the XNamespace declaration and the `brk + "node1"` and I didn't get an exception, so I'm not sure why that didn't work for you.

Comment: Im not sure that is it!? Iv tried brk+"node1". It seems to be depended on whether you set the namepace up on the constructor of the rootelement or the Add method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that the root element needs to have the namespace as well:

```
XElement root = new XElement("Root",
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "brk", "http://somewhere.com"));
```

needs to be:

```
XElement root = new XElement(brk + "Root",
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "brk", "http://somewhere.com"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is solotuion and working fine.

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Xml.Linq;
    using System.Xml.XPath;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

    namespace CreateSampleXML
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();            
                XNamespace xm = "http://somewhere.com";
                XElement rt= new XElement("Root", new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "brk", "http://somewhere.com"));
                XElement cNode = new XElement("child1");
                cNode.Add(new XElement(xm + "node1", 123456));
                cNode.Add(new XElement(xm + "node2", 500000000));
                rt.Add(cNode);
                XDocument doc2 = new XDocument(rt);
                doc2.Save(@"C:\sample3.xml");
            }
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Please discuss your code on your answer. Don't just give the code.

Comment: That is solution. @EvertonAgner